# Unable to use Update Log: _version_fiels must exist in schema

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I am new at solr apache and i am trying to build a search engine based on this platform. i uploaded all the documents but it continue to give me such a error i don't know what going on. this error bring other errors like CoreContainer which unable to create core files and i am not able to perform a query search. Can you help me guys??

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: _version_ field must exist in schema and be searchable (indexed or docValues) and retrievable(stored or docValues) and not multiValued (_version_ does not exist)
at org.apache.solr.update.VersionInfo.getAndCheckVersionField(VersionInfo.java:68)
at org.apache.solr.update.VersionInfo.<init>(VersionInfo.java:94)
at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog.init(UpdateLog.java:308)
at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.<init>(UpdateHandler.java:137)
at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.<init>(UpdateHandler.java:94)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.<init>(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:102)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:706)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createUpdateHandler(SolrCore.java:768)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initUpdateHandler(SolrCore.java:1009)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:874)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:776)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:842)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$0(CoreContainer.java:498)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$$Lambda$24/135640095.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$$Lambda$25/328827614.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Those are my field build in schema.xml

```
 <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="revision" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="user" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="userId" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="text" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<uniqueKey> id </uniqueKey>
```

Comment: Have you reloaded the core after changing the schema? Was the field present when you indexed the documents? Your schema.xml should also contain more than what you've defined, but I guess you've left parts out. Be sure to also set `_version_` to `multiValued="false"`, and use the correct schema version (check the example for your Solr version)

Answer (score 0):

first you download latest configset associated with schema Latest configset can be downloaded using following command: solr zk -downconfig -d directory to download -n configset name -z ip:port of zookeeper

for example : solr zk -downconfig -d C:\solr\workingConfig -n configsetName -z localhost:2181

make required changes in schema.xml
add *version* if it does not exist

Then Upload latest configset to zookeeper using following command.

solr zk -upconfig -d directory to upload -n configset name -z ip:port of zookeeper For example: solr zk -upconfig -d C:\solr\workingConfig -n configsetName -z localhost:2181

Then you need to Reload schema so that changes can take effect immediately.

Schema can be reloaded using following command: http://ip:port/solr/admin/collections?action=RELOAD&name=

And then try to add docs